# Есть ли в PL/SQL эквивалент цикла foreach-loop?

Tags: oracle, plsql, foreach

Нужно перебрать в цикле около десяти строк. Все строки известны заранее, *их не нужно получать запросом* откуда-либо.

Пробую:

```sql
BEGIN
    FOR tab IN ('one', 'two', 'three')
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || tab;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Но так не работает, получаю ошибку:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:

Есть ли способ сделать это?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle PL equivalent of foreach-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67377584) от участника [@Mikhail T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1747834/mikhail-t)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67377584

Answer (score 3):

```
declare
   type t_strings is table of varchar2(100);
   strings t_strings:=t_strings('one','two','three');
begin
   for i in 1..strings.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line(strings(i));
   end loop;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
one
two
three
```

---

Или можно использовать свои собственные ["почти одострочные" функции](http://orasql.org/2017/10/02/plsql-functions-iterate-and-keys-for-associative-arrays/).

Стоит заметить, в 21c имеются некоторые новые возможности для `FOR-LOOP`:

- [1.1.1 PL/SQL Extended Iterators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/release-changes.html#GUID-60026B49-A592-4F2A-83FC-5C755695F850)
- [FOR LOOP Iteration Enhancements in Oracle Database 21c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/21c/for-loop-iteration-enhancements-21c)

Пример выше можно будет переписать так:

```
declare
   type t_strings is table of varchar2(100);
begin
   for str in values of t_strings('one','two','three') loop
      dbms_output.put_line(str);
   end loop;
end;
/
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67377821) от участника [@Sayan Malakshinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429100/sayan-malakshinov)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Известный со старых версий, классический и "почти настоящий" `foreach-loop`:

```
declare 
    type tabList is table of varchar2(32);
    tabs tabList := tabList ('one', 'two', 'three');
    curr varchar2(32) := tabs.first;
begin
    <<foreach>> loop exit foreach when curr is null;
        execute immediate 'create table '||tabs(curr)||' (col char(1))';
        execute immediate 'drop table '  ||tabs(curr)||' purge';
        curr := tabs.next (curr);
    end loop;
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67396873) от участника [@0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb)</sub>